# Simple recursive series in matlab

Tags: recursion, matlab

I'm trying to get the sum of the first 120 terms of a series:

a(n) = (10+a(n-1))(1.005)^n

I've tried two approaches, but I don't know which mistakes I'm making.

Approach #1:

```
nval = 1 

mval = zeros(120,1)

for nval=1:120
    if nval <= 120               %counting up from 1 to 120
        if nval == 1              %modifying first term to avoid 0 index
            mval(1) = (10)*(1.005)   
            nval = nval +1;
        else
            mval(nval) = (10+mval(nval-1))*(1.005)^nval;  %Assigning 
            nval = nval +1;
        end

    end
end
```

which results in a column vector with 10.05 at the top and zeroes for the rest. If if omit the opening definition of mval as zeroes, I get the same result as

Approach #2:

```
a(1)=10.05;    %defining first term to avoid 0 index

for n=2:120, a(n)= (10+a(n-1))*(1.005)^n;  end
```

which results in something far too large.

(The correct value for a(120) is ~1646.99)

***Edit: my mistake and apologies - my series was wrong; the (1.005)^n is NOT to the nth power, but merely 1.005. Using this, both methods work. 
Thanks to one and all for answers and suggestions***

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expectation for `mval(120)` to approximately equal `1646.99`. Are you sure the presented equation is the correct one?

Comment: There's no way that `mval(120)` or `a(120)` is equal to 1646.99, especially since the base value that is being exponentiated gets larger as `n` gets large.  However, getting rid of `nval = nval+1` in your loop will solve your problem of at least computing the sequence right, but the expected result of 1646.99 is totally not correct.  Also, approach #2 is correct.  It also matches with approach #1 once you remove the superfluous incrementing of `nval` in the loop.  As far as I can see, you're implementing the recursive formula correctly... so double check the actual answer at `a(120)`.

Comment: I answered below that you’re incrementing at the end of a `for` loop, which you should only do for a `while` loop, but excaza reported that doesn’t cause your problem.  Therefore, I’m leaving this comment and deleting my answer.

Comment: OP, this statement: `which results in a column vector with 10.05 at the top and zeroes for the rest` is not accurate. What you're seeing is the `mval(1) = (10)*(1.005)` line displaying (you have not supressed the output for that line with a semicolon), not the final value of `mval`.

Comment: Is the ”too large” answer you’re getting, by any chance, 73061.51699011266?

Comment: @Agawa001 No it absolutely does not. Code that is not working is completely off-topic on Code Review.